# Adding button groups using seesaw

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I am creating a GUI using seesaw for the first time and I am stuck on how to add buttons to button groups and display them(buttons) on the same frame. This is what I have so far.

```
(def b (button :text "Start a new Project"))

(def c (button :text "Continue an Existing Project"))


(def groups (button-group))

(flow-panel :items [(b :group groups)
                        (c :group groups)])

(display groups)
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to display button b and c on the same frame.With the code I have, I get the following error;java.lang.ClassCastException: seesaw.core.proxy$javax.swing.JButton$Tag$fd407141 cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(button)` returns a button (a component) which is not a function. If you later use it as `(b :group groups)`, it actually tries to invoke `b` as if it was a function, passing it two arguments: `:group` and `groups`. That's why it fails, because it can't cast button to function.

Secondly, I believe `(button)` creates a regular `JButton`, for which the group makes little sense. Did you mean radio buttons, like `(radio)`?

One of these two should probably do what you expect.

Radio buttons:

```clj
(def groups (button-group))

(def b (radio :text "Start a new Project" :group groups))

(def c (radio :text "Continue an Existing Project" :group groups))

(def panel
  (flow-panel :items [b c]))

(invoke-later
  (-> (frame :content panel :on-close :dispose) pack! show!))
```

Regular buttons:

```clj
(def b (button :text "Start a new Project"))

(def c (button :text "Continue an Existing Project"))

(def panel
  (flow-panel :items [b c]))

(invoke-later
  (-> (frame :content panel :on-close :dispose) pack! show!))
```

You probably can use your `(display)` function instead of this `(invoke-later)` snippet here, but this works end-to-end for me.

Comment: Thank you Konrad for the great explanation!It worked!